# My google map DIV sits on top of everything else - can't see why

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I have a page with multiple divs and sections, I want the top nav div to be fixed and on top of everything, then all the divs/sections in the page scroll under it, then the final div is my google map which is fixed at the bottom of the page but under everything, so that as you scroll to the bottom the map is unveiled rather than scrolls into view.

Problem: The code below draws the google map in the right place (bottom) but ontop of everything.

If I set the z-index to -1 of mapcontainer then all sorts of crazy happens (the bg image of hobbiescontainer disappears, topnav is no longer fixed and if I scroll down and back up it disappears entirely)

If I remove the google maps API then everything works as expected.

Therefore based on the above I am guessing that the issue is related to the fact that the map is being put into the div once everything has been rendered and throwing off my z-index, but I'm not really sure.  Can anyone help?

Apologies for amount of code - as it involves positioning I thought maybe some of my other elements are causing issues so best put it all in.

have loaded code to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/rwg4wqfo/4/

```
     <body>

    <nav id="topbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#intro">Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#wexp">Work Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="#hobbies">Hobbies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="navspace"></div>
    <section id="introductionSection">
        <a id="intro"><span id="imageCropper"><img src="/images/me.jpg" / id="imageOfMe" /></span></a>
        <h1>Who am I?</h1>
        <p class="keyText">
            <!-- content here -->
        </p>
    </section>

    <section id="skillsSection">
        <a id="skills"><h2>My Skills/Knowledge</h2></a>
        <p class="keyText">
            <!-- content here -->
        </p>
    </section>

    <section id="workExperienceSection">
        <a id="wexp"><h3>Work Experience</h3></a>
        <p class="keytext">
            <!-- content here -->
        </p>
    </section>
    <div id="hobbiescontainer">
    <section id="hobbiesSection">
        <a id="hobbies"><h4>Hobbies</h4></a>
        <p class="keytext">
            <!-- content here -->
        </p>
    </section>
    </div>
    <section id="contactSection">
        <a id="contact"><h5>Contact</h5></a>
        <p class="keytext">
            <!-- content here -->
        </p>
    </section>

    <div id="mapcontainer">
        <div id="map"></div>   
    </div>
    <div id="mapspace"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBa5Gt2bp2Oxnc_1NqN1wxGKJjuHqJ9y_4"></script>
    <script src="CHJS.js"></script>

</body>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
body
{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
text-align:justify;

height: 100%;
min-height:800px;
background-color:rgba(125,185,232,1); 
background-image: url(images/fallback-gradient.png); 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(30,87,153,1)), to(rgba(255,255,255,1)));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1), rgba(255,255,255,1)); 
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1), rgba(255,255,255,1));
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1), rgba(255,255,255,1));
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1), rgba(255,255,255,1));
z-index:1;
}

ul, li
{
list-style-type:none;
display:inline;
}

p {
padding: 0px 25% 0px 25%;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
font-size: 30px;
font-family: Calibri,Verdana,arial,serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform:uppercase;
width:50%;
position: relative;
left: 15%;
}

button {
float:right;
margin: 30px 100px 0px 0px;
font-family:calibri,verdana,arial,serif;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:normal;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

#navspace {
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
}

#topbar {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color: rgba(232,232,232,1);
background-image: url(images/fallback-gradient.png); 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(242,242,242,1)), to(rgba(232,232,232,1)));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(242,242,242,1), rgba(232,232,232,1)); 
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(242,242,242,1), rgba(232,232,232,1));
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(242,242,242,1), rgba(232,232,232,1));
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(242,242,242,1), rgba(232,232,232,1));

height: 50px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid rgba(195,195,195,1);
z-index: 9999;
}

#introductionSection {
background-color: white;
padding: 20px 0 0 0;
overflow:auto;
}

#imageCropper
{
height:100px;
width:100px;
vertical-align:middle;
border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
margin:3px;
border: 1px solid rgba(195,195,195,1);
position: relative;
left: 100px;
}

#imageOfMe
{
position:relative;
left:-53%;
top:-65%;
height:180px;
}

#skillsSection {
background-color: grey;
padding: 0px;
overflow:auto;
margin: 0px;
z-index:1;
}

#workExperienceSection {
background-color: white;
padding: 0px;
overflow:auto;
}

#hobbiescontainer {
background-image: url(Images/hockey.jpg);
background-position:center;
background-size:cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
padding: 10% 0 10% 0;
}

#hobbiesSection {
background-color: grey;
padding: 0px;
overflow:auto;
}

#contactSection {
background-color:white;
padding: 0px;
overflow:auto;
}

#mapcontainer {
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width: 100%;
min-height:100%;
padding:0;
border:0;
z-index:0;
}

#map {
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
}

#mapspace {
height: 400px;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Can you host this somewhere with all the assets in place?

Comment: You're on the right track with z-index controls, just wrap all the other content besides the map container with z-index 1 and let mapcontainer be 0

Comment: Elzi - tried that but has no impact.  Displays as it should except for the map being on top of everything.  As it was without the wrapper.

Comment: z-index only applies to positioned elements. Have you made sure to use `position: relative;` with any previously unpositioned elements when changing z-index?

Comment: Having followed @isherwood advice on positioning and z-index it works as intended in Firefox, it works in IE11 (but the fixed map and fixed background both 'vibrate' when you scroll), and in Chrome the background-image on #hobbiescontainer behaves strangely. Sometimes it's visible in the padding, other times it's not, and sometimes the background-image scrolls and sometimes it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#topbar, #navspace, #hobbiescontainer, section {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/rwg4wqfo/5

Note that your approach removes access to the map for purposes of scrolling, clicking, etc.

Comment: So I went through as per your previous suggestion and added position:relative and z-index: 1 to unpositioned elements and now the topbar doesn't stay fixed, and the background image for hobbiescontainer isn't visible.  Also yes noted that about the access to the map but thought I'd deal with one issue at a time.  Is that because it's behind another element so it's not possible to "reach" it with the cursor?

Comment: Sorry couldn't edit in time.  The above was true when I had the wrapping container as suggested by elzi but taking that out - the background-image on #hobbiescontainer behaves strangely.  Sometimes it's visible in the padding, other times it's not, and sometimes the background-image scrolls and sometimes it doesn't